# When were capital punishments suspended during the Rashidun caliphate?

Tags: law, caliphate

The wikipedia entry about [Rashidun Caliphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashidun_Caliphate#Judicial_administration) says:

> Various Islamic lawyers do however place multiple conditions, and stipulations e.g. the poor cannot be penalised for stealing out of poverty, before executing such a law, making it very difficult to reach such a stage. It is well known during a time of drought in the Rashidun caliphate period, **capital punishments were suspended** until the effects of the drought passed.

When did this drought happen? When did the authorities suspend capital punishments?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, this traces back to oral tradition and so you are unlikely to find any precise record of when the drought or judgment occurred. But the judgment is specifically attributed to Umar, and he was caliph from August 634 CE to November 644 CE.

Comment: Not a huge range there.